# UWP/C# ItemsControl Multiple Boxes?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have had a lot of help so far with creating the correct formatting for an ItemsControl panel and appreciate this communities help so far with helping me troubleshoot coding issues. 
Im currently at a rather small hurdle where im trying to figure out how to create multiple boxes within the same ItemsControl. Currently the overall view looks like this:

[image]

Im a little stumped and would just like a little guidance really as to where to put the other XAML lines. 
I need it to look like this:

[image]

Here is my code currently (its all nested within a Frame):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource userDataCollection}" Margin="40,40,40,725"  Width="Auto" Height="310">
                    <!-- Changing Orientation of VirtualizingStackPanel -->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>                            
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <!-- Change header for ItemsControl -->
                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Accounts At A Glance" FontSize="28" Foreground="#b880fc" Padding="12"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Template>


                    <!-- Template for each card-->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="240" Height="240" Background="Gray" Margin="30,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="4">

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="24"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding PayDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="14" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="14"/>

                            </Grid>


                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

I really apologise for this, im trying to learn as much as i can as i go. Im mainly stuggling with the XAML formatting and incorperating learning material into my project :/ Any help would be amazing

Comment: Its worth noting that i did come across the GridView.ItemsPanel <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/> but this was removed in the last post due to it interfering with the text formatting. I believe this is what i need to try to introduce back but maybe not ItemsWrapGrid, maybe just ItemGrid or something?

Comment: You should use `GridView` instead of `ItemControl`.

Comment: Hi Dishant, I was advised that ItemControl would be best for this layout. I tried using GridView but had similar issues :/ One of my last posts was advised against using GridView

Comment: To be sure I understand: your problem with the ItemsControl is that only one of the items is showing up?

Comment: Yes, to an extent. It only displays the one square when ideally, i would like it to display a few squares of data. It may very well be an issue with my "Data" storage. I dont know how the ItemsControl reads the date. I probably need to sort out the UserData class. Macs solution below seems to create multiple "Users" and i feel like i should probably be doing that for mine aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an alternative approach for your problem. This uses "semi" MVVM approach  (browse through the net and study this pattern).

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<User> _userCollection;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<User> UserCollection
    {
        get => _userCollection;
        set
        {
            _userCollection = value;
            NotifyProperyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyProperyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User
            {
                Name = "John Doe",
                PayDate = DateTime.Now,
                NumberOfItems = 1
            },
            new User
            {
                Name = "John Doe 2",
                PayDate = DateTime.Now,
                NumberOfItems = 1
            },
            new User
            {
                Name = "John Doe 3",
                PayDate = DateTime.Now,
                NumberOfItems = 1
            },
        };
    }
}
```

The view (got rid of some styling temporarily):

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="using:App1.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    Loaded="MainPage_OnLoaded">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="15"  Width="Auto" Height="310">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <!-- Template for each card-->
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="200" Height="100" Background="Gray" Margin="15,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="4">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="24"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding PayDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="14" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Width="220" FontSize="14"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

View's code-behind:

```
namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MainPageViewModel VM => (MainPageViewModel) DataContext;

        private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VM.LoadData();
        }
    }

}
```

Output:
[image]
Next steps:

- Apply your styling. Study how to limit grid columns.
- Improve the code
  further, in MVVM you shouldn't really have implementations on the
  code-behind, so study for ICommand, Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Mac that is a huge help! I will implement this and see how i get on!

Comment: Hi Mac, i understand you used two way as a variable for the itemscontrol. Does this allow the data to be edited? Im not going to be editing anything in these boxes, they will be purely for display purposes only :) Just wanted to know if i should look at removing this and replacing with oneway to only display data

Comment: Hey @Batteredburrito, yeah you can change it to oneway or simply just don't specify the Mode as by default it's oneway, I forgot to remove that and didn't bother cleaning up my mess, I think the scrollviewer can be also be removed, I just got used to doing those things >.<

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Im going through and cleaning up some of my messy practices as i type :) Youre guidance is doing wonders so thank you very much. Also, thank you for signing up and contributing! Youve saved my bacon. No doubt bump into you on another thread at some point. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It perfect now.

Im an idiot.

I essentially needed to seperate the information presented within the UserData.cs Class. I didnt understand how the information was being read but understand it now. The XAML has been left untouched as it works currently for what i need. It will be update to follow the MVVM format as mentioned by Mac. Here is the UserData.CS class located inside a data folder:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BudgetSheet.Data
{
    public class UserData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PayDate { get; set; }
        public string NumberOfItems { get; set; }
    }

    class UserDataCollection : ObservableCollection<UserData>
    {
        public UserDataCollection()
        {

            // Placeholder, needs to be replaced with CSV or Database information
            this.Add(new UserData()
            {
                Name = "Selected Username",
                PayDate = "Friday",
                NumberOfItems = "ItemAmount Placeholder"
            });
            // Placeholder for user 2
            this.Add(new UserData()
            {
                Name = "Selected Username 2",
                PayDate = "Friday 2",
                NumberOfItems = "ItemAmount Placeholder 2"
            });
            // Placeholder for user 3
            this.Add(new UserData()
            {
                Name = "Selected Username 3",
                PayDate = "Friday 3",
                NumberOfItems = "ItemAmount Placeholder 3"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what it was before hand and why there were issues with information display:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BudgetSheet.Data
{
    public class UserData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PayDate { get; set; }
        public string NumberOfItems { get; set; }
    }

    class UserDataCollection : ObservableCollection<UserData>
    {
        public UserDataCollection()
        {

            // Placeholder, needs to be replaced with CSV or Database information
            this.Add(new UserData()
            {
                Name = "Selected Username",

            });
            // Placeholder for user selected PayDate
            this.Add(new UserData()
            {

                PayDate = "Friday",

            });
            // Placeholder for user selected PayDate
            this.Add(new UserData()
            {

                NumberOfItems = "ItemAmount Placeholder"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This solution does not provide much flexibility currently but it works for the formatting. Marking as resolved to close the ticket